# Adding hover text to Plotly scatter plot lines or multiple colors for scatter plot lines

Tags: python, plotly, plotly-python

I have a plotly Scatter plot with traces for markers and traces for lines connecting the markers. Each line between markers represents a weighted connection and so I've been trying to figure out how to visually demonstrate this. Initially I tried just varying the colour of each line but the "line" dict in a Scatter object doesn't have the option for a list of colours. Then I tried setting the hover info over each line but the text doesn't appear on hover. I'm wondering if there's a way to accomplish varying colours/hover info text or if there's a better way to do this that I'm missing?

Edit:

Code for creating the edge traces:

```
edge_trace = go.Scatter(
x=[],
y=[],
text=[],
hoverinfo='text',
mode='lines',
line=dict(width=0.5, color="#888"))
```

The text and x,y are populated later on, I know this works fine, the text just doesn't show up when I hover over the line

[image]

Comment: Can you include your code and graph to make it more easy to visualize what you're trying to achieve?

Comment: Yes, just added the text and an image, sorry if the previous was vague